# stack <div> elements within a "row" class Bootstrap4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to find a way to stack an element within a row class.

See JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jLhvmq24/2/

I need small tag "Enter Business Email" to show-up below the input box

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-group col-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email address">
    <small class="text-muted">Enter Business Email.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <button class="btn btn-light">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `d-block` to the small tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Use the outer most parent(`row`) to `flex row`(by default it displays row).
> 2. Since you need the text to be below the `input` so add `flex-direction:column;` to the `.input-group` class.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/uewno2kj/3/)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-group col-10 mb-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email address">
    <small class="text-muted">Enter Business Email.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <button class="btn btn-light" type="button">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bs4 has built-in classes : d-flex and flex-column : https://jsfiddle.net/eu18ka0s/  ;)

Comment: Yeah I remember this but didn't ring the bell during that time! will keep this point :) thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use grids to solve it.

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
     "input"
     "small";
}

.input-1 {
  grid-area: input;
}

.small-1 {
  grid-area: small;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="input-group col-10 container">
     <input type="text" class="form-control input-1" placeholder="email address">
     <small class="text-muted small-1">Enter Business Email.</small>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2">
     <button class="btn btn-light">Subscribe</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

You can remove the padding overwriting it from the Bootstrap cols classes